# find the same year in two different columns in the same mysql table

Tags: mysql

I need to do a mysql query that will answer the question in president's table - where there any years when presidents were born and when other presidents died?

The presidents table has the following 
Last_name, first_name, birth, death, state, city

I tried

SELECT * FROM president WHERE YEAR(birth) = YEAR(death);
But I got empty sets.

What am I missing here? help!

Comment: If the optimizer knew the US Constitution it would know the constraint that `YEAR(death)` has to be at least `YEAR(birth)+35` for any particular person who held the office of president.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is query the presidents table and then re-join the table on itself matching the death date with the birth date.

```
SELECT * FROM presidents p1
JOIN presidents p2
ON p1.birth = p2.death
```

This only returns the rows that have presidents births matching presidents deaths.  If you would like all births you can use `LEFT JOIN` and for all deaths, you can use `RIGHT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM president WHERE YEAR(birth) in (Select YEAR(death) from president);
```

or if you actually want to have the list of years:

```
SELECT distinct YEAR(birth) FROM president WHERE YEAR(birth) in
(Select YEAR(death) from president);
```

or you could also solve it with a join:

```
SELECT * FROM president p1 inner join president p2 on (YEAR(p1.birth) = YEAR(p2.death));
```

EDIT:
to explain what you were missing in your statement. You were only comparing the birth-year and the death-year of the same president. You didn't compare the row with other rows.